# Speed up simple R code (vectorize?)

Tags: r, performance

I have two positive integer vectors specifying start and end "positions" of ranges

```
starts <- sample(10^6,replace = T)
ends <- starts+sample(100:1000,length(starts),replace=T)
```

So these specify 1000000 ranges that are 100 to 1000 units long. 
Now I want to know how many times a position (positive integer) is "covered" by a range. For this I do:

```
coverage <- integer(max(ends))
for(i in seq(length(starts))) {
      coverage[starts[i]:ends[i]] <- coverage[starts[i]:ends[i]] + 1 
}
```

But because of the for loop, it's relatively slow. For billions of ranges, it can take a very long time. 
I cannot find a way to vectorize this code. I could split the work and use multiple CPUs, but the speed gain would be marginal. apply, lapply and other meta-functions do not improve speed (as expected). For instance

```
coverage <- tabulate(unlist(Map(':', starts,ends)))
```

is also slow because of the "Map" part. I fear it also takes more memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about running `density` with a rectangular window on start + 50

Comment: But the size of ranges may not be always the same. I edited my code to make that clear.

Comment: Your main problem is not the loop or `Map`, rather the `:` funciton probably. Vectorizing it is indeed seem to be a very frequent request on SO... Kudos for the reproducible example and nice attempts. Though you don't really need `10^6` in order to create a *minimal* reproducible example. And it is always a good practice to add a `set.seed` when creating data sets with functions that use a random seed. Also, showing the desired output makes it easier to read (though it's not such a big of deal in your case).

Comment: If I replace `:` by `+` in the `Map` call, it's still much, much slower than simply `starts+ends`. So Map is slow compared to vectorized code.

Comment: It's not about `Map` specifically, it's about how many times you need to evaluate a function + how efficient that function is. If you replace `:` with `+` it takes about a second on my machine (compared to 7 seconds for `:`). It's not *that* bad for evaluating a function 1e6 times. In worse case scenario, you could write a vectorized version for `:` in Rcpp and get over with.

Comment: Anyhow, `Map` is impractical in my case, as I can have billions of ranges that may each cover hundreds of positions. So the `unlist(Map())` call would generate a vector of length ~10^11, on which I can call `tabulate`. It would use much more memory than the for loop, without being faster.

Comment: So vectorization is not an option in your case, eh? Simply because you won't have enough memory.

Comment: Is the number of rows always significantly higher than the spread of the range? Looping seems to be required on one of the both axes anyhow from an algorithmic point of view so it would be better to loop over the columns (I could imagine using a data table with the start-end-ranges, looping from min to max of `ends` and counting the row hits for the condition "col.number >= start && col.number <= ends"...

Comment: "IRanges" package seems to handle what you're trying to do: `tmp = coverage(IRanges(starts, ends)); ans = rep(runValue(tmp), runLength(tmp))`;  `all.equal(coverage, ans)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a count of ranges that start and end at any specific index and then apply a cumulative sum over the difference of these.

1. Aggregate the number of ranges that start at each index
2. Aggregate the number of ranges that end at one position before each index (if `ends` are inclusive)
3. Calculate the net change: `count of starts - count of ends`
4. Loop over indexes and sum up the net changes cumulatively. This will give the number ranges that started earlier than this index and not ended yet at this index.

The "covered" number is equal to this cumulative sum at each index.

I tried this approach using sparse vectors to cut down on memory usage. Although it may be faster with normal vectors, not sure.
With `sparseVector` it was 5.7x faster than the loop approach for the given example.

```
library(Matrix)

set.seed(123)

starts <- sample(10^6,replace = T)
ends <- starts+sample(100:1000,length(starts),replace=T)

v.cov <- NULL
fun1 <- function() {
  coverage <- integer(max(ends))
  for(i in seq(length(starts))) {
    coverage[starts[i]:ends[i]] <- coverage[starts[i]:ends[i]] + 1 
  }
  v.cov <<- coverage
}
# Testing "for loop" approach
system.time(fun1())
# user  system elapsed 
# 21.84    0.00   21.83 

v.sum <- NULL
fun2 <- function() {      
  # 1. Aggregate the number of ranges that start at each index
  t.starts <- table(starts)
  i.starts <- strtoi(names(t.starts))
  x.starts <- as.vector(t.starts)
  sv.starts <- sparseVector(x=x.starts, i=i.starts, length=max(ends)+1)  # to match length of sv.ends below
  # 2. Aggregate the number of ranges that end at one position before each index
  t.ends <- table(ends)
  i.ends <- strtoi(names(t.ends))+1  # because "ends" are inclusive 
  x.ends <- as.vector(t.ends)
  sv.ends <- sparseVector(x=x.ends, i=i.ends, length=max(ends)+1)

  sv.diff <- sv.starts - sv.ends
  v.sum <<- cumsum(sv.diff)[1:max(ends)]  # drop last element
}
# Testing "cumulative sum" approach
system.time(fun2())
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.828   0.000   3.823

identical(v.cov, v.sum)
# TRUE
```

Also, there is probably a better way to extract x's and i's for `sparseVector` constructor than using `table` and `strtoi(names(x))`that may boost speed further.

**EDIT**

Avoid `strtoi` using a 1-column `sparseMatrix` instead

```
v.sum.mat <- NULL
fun3 <- function() {
  v.ones <- rep(1, length(starts))
  m.starts <- sparseMatrix(i=starts, j=v.ones, x=v.ones, dims=c(max(ends)+1,1))
  m.ends <- sparseMatrix(i=ends+1, j=v.ones, x=v.ones, dims=c(max(ends)+1,1))
  m.diff <- m.starts - m.ends
  v.sum.mat <<- cumsum(m.diff[,1])[1:max(ends)]
}
# Testing "cumulative sum" approach using matrix
system.time(fun3())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.456   0.028   0.486 

identical(v.cov, v.sum.mat)
# TRUE
```

**EDIT 2 - super fast, super short**

Based on comment by @alexis_laz, thank you!

```
fun4 <- function() {
  cumsum(tabulate(starts, max(ends) + 1L) - tabulate(ends + 1L, max(ends) + 1L))[1:max(ends)]
}
system.time(v.sum.tab <- fun4())
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.040   0.000   0.041 

identical(as.integer(v.cov), v.sum.tab)
# TRUE
```

Comment: nice idea; a non-sparse alternative is `cumsum(tabulate(starts, max(ends) + 1L) - tabulate(ends + 1L, max(ends) + 1L))[1:max(ends)]`

Comment: That's a nice one. Not sure how memory efficient but certainly fast. Just a few notes. `-(max(ends) + 1)` will be probably faster than `1:max(ends)`. Also, no need in `<<-`. Just assign the result to `v.sum.mat` outside the function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for the comments.
I added EDIT 2 without <<-. Not sure whether it's good practice to correct previously posted code to also omit <<-, is it?
I don't get the `- (max(ends) + 1)` part, can you point out the line?

Comment: Your fun4() does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!